# On the Adapter class How to get key and value from HashMap

Tags: android, hashmap

On my `RecyclerViewAdapter` class i'm passing `HashMap<String,ArrayList<Custom>>` as data, now i want to get key & value for every position but i don't know how i should do this! thanks in advance

```
public class Main_Recycler_Single_Row extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Main_Recycler_Single_Row.ViewHolder> {



private Context mContext;
private HashMap<String,ArrayList<Products>> dataSet;

public Main_Recycler_Single_Row(Context mContext, HashMap<String,ArrayList<Products>> mDataSet) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.dataSet = mDataSet;

} @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<Products>> entry=(Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<Products>>) dataSet.entrySet();//this line is my problem!


    holder.header.setText(entry.getKey());

    holder.mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    holder.mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    holder.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new Main_Recycler_Sinle_Item(mContext,entry.getValue()));

}
```

Comment: what's the problem ? any error ?

Comment: warning:unchecked cast , on the Map.Entry line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get `Value` from `HashMap` using `position`, you also need to maintain `Array` of `keys`

```
keys = (String[])mDataSet.keySet().toArray();
```

Your `ViewHolder` class will look like:

```
public Main_Recycler_Single_Row(Context mContext, HashMap<String,ArrayList<Products>> mDataSet) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.dataSet = mDataSet;
    keys = (String[])mDataSet.keySet().toArray();

} @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.header.setText(keys[position]);

    holder.mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    holder.mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    holder.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new Main_Recycler_Sinle_Item(mContext,dataSet.get(keys[position])));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use entry.getvalue(); for getting values

```
String key = entry.getKey(); ArrayList<Products> value = entry.getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you :

```
holder.header.setText(dataSet.getKey().toArray()[position]);// for key
holder.productDesc.setText(dataSet.get(position)
.get(productPosition).getDesc())  //sample for getting product description
```

Answer (score 0):

To get value:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    // key
    String key = (new ArrayList<>(tab.keySet())).get(position);
    // value
    Object value = Objects.requireNonNull(tab.get(key));

    TextView textView = holder.textRecyclerView;
    textView.setText(value);
}
```